# How do I set the API cache directory apicache-py3 and throttle.ctrl for pywikibot?

Tags: pywikibot

By default pywikibot makes a cache directory `apicache-py3` and a file `throttle.ctrl` in the current directory, from where I run my Python script.

I would like pywikibot to put those elsewhere, e.g. in `../data`. How can I direct pywikibot, from my Python script, to do that?